# Putty IP address of client - passing to terminal?

Tags: ip, putty

Please can anyone help - when launching Putty from a desktop machine is it possible to pass the value of the IP address of the Windows machine to the server session?

Comment: Well, do you want the IP that the windows machine thinks it is, or the IP that the server thinks the windows machine is?  These may be different because of NAT.

Comment: Ideally I want the IP that the windows machine thinks it is because I'd like to use in conjuction with DISPLAY=10.X.X.X:0.0 export DISPLAY

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty/119908#119908

Comment: Many thanks - the way I'm using a Xwindows is a bit unusal - basically I launch Exceed - the do the above command with the IP.  Can you tell me where this $SSH_CLIENT variable comes from - it's there on my initial login, is it being set in profile anywhere?  I ask as when I sudo to another account it's gone ... is there a way to keep it?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to figure out the information of the SSH client from the server after the client is connected, then look at the SSH_CLIENT variable that is probably set.

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT
192.168.32.26 62221 22
```

Comment: That works!  Thankyou!  - However I now realise I need to carry this into another sudo - is that possible?

Comment: Uhm, sure, something like this maybe?  `sudo bash -c "export MYTEST=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}; export"`  Do see the link I posted, if you are just looking for normal SSH X11 forwarding though.

Answer (score 1):

> ideally I want the IP that the windows machine thinks it is because I'd like to use in conjuction with DISPLAY=10.X.X.X:0.0 export DISPLAY

Can't you just tick `Enable X11 Forwarding` on  `Connection->SSH->X11` ?

Comment: Thanks, that created a file .Xauthority file in my home folder but I'm not sure what I can do with it?

Comment: Presumably you have an Xserver running on your windows system so at a shell prompt run an X11 program ? e.g. `firefox &`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can do things like:

```
putty -telnet 10.1.2.3
putty -ssh 10.2.3.4
putty -serial com4
```

Here are the various cli arguments you can pass to the executable:

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The arguments you posted are simply to connect to the server at the given IP address; the OP's question is to determine the client's IP address from the shell and apply the address to an environment variable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- completely misunderstood the question.  Zoredache has the actual answer.  =)